# How do I properly initialize and assign a observable using angulafire2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2, rxjs6

I'm using Angular 6 and Rxjs 6.

The following code will throw undefined at the `ListFormsComponent` over and over and over until the `Observable` is assigned by `getForms()` at which it will then display the data. The `getForms()` is called by the navigation service when attempting to navigate to `ListFormsComponent` page.

FormService.ts

```
export class FormService {

  public forms$: Observable <Array<Form>> ;
  public assignedForms$: Observable <Array<Form>> ;
  public form$: Observable <Form>;
  constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private authService: AuthService,
  ) {}

  getForms() {
    let zippedData = zip(this.authService.user$);
    zippedData.subscribe(data => {
      this.forms$ = this.afs.collection('networks')
        .doc(data[0].activeNetworkProfile.id)
        .collection('companyProfiles')
        .doc(data[0].activeCompanyProfile.id)
        .collection<Forms>('inspectionForms')
        .valueChanges();
    })
  }

}
```

ListFormsComponent.ts

```
export class ListFormsComponent implements OnInit {
  public forms: Forms[];
  constructor(private formService: FormService, private navigateService: NavigationService) {

    this.formService.forms$.subscribe(forms => { //<---Error here this.formService.forms$ is undefined
      this.forms = forms;
      console.log("Forms inside component");
      console.log(this.forms);
    })
  }
}
```

ListFormsComponent.html

```
<mbsc-listview [options]="listSettings" style="display:none">
  <mbsc-listview-item (click)="viewDetails(form.id)" *ngFor="let form of forms">
    <h3 class="mbsc-lv-txt">{{form.name}}</h3>
    <p class="mbsc-lv-txt">{{form.lastEdited | date: 'medium'}} </p>
  </mbsc-listview-item>
</mbsc-listview>
```

NavigationService.ts

```
navigateForms() {
  this.formService.getForms();
  this.navigateService.navigate('forms');
}
```

So I then decided to initialize the observable by doing the following code(see below) in the constructor of FormService.ts and it stops the errors but It does not trigger the subscription in the `ListFormsComponent.ts`. I'm assuming when `valueChanges()` returns the `Observable` to `forms$` it breaks rest of the `subscriptions`.

```
this.forms$ = new Observable<Array<Forms>>();
```

Comment: For a test, could you please check if `getForms` from `FormService` actually yields a value? I'm a bit skeptical about that. You might wanna subscribe to `valueChanges` right there and log whatever is returned to the console.

Also the `forms` inside the Component is set asynchronously. So until it gets resolved it will give you an error on the console.

Comment: It actually does work, I get values back but for some reason it does not trigger the subscription made in FormsListComponent.ts

Comment: Updated my answer. Please check. I'm pretty sure that was the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue is in this function:

```
navigateForms() {
  this.formService.getForms();
  this.navigateService.navigate('forms');
}
```

You've called `this.formService.getForms();` which will initialize `forms$` on `FormService`. But simultaneously, you're also navigating to `forms` which will render the `ListFormsComponent`. In your `ListFormsComponent` you're doing `formService.forms$` which might not have initialized at that point. Hence you're getting it as `undefined`.

Instead of using the `forms$`, I would have simply returned the `Observable` value from the `getForms` method and I would have called it in the `ListFormComponent`'s `ngOnInit` method:

```
export class FormService {

  public forms$: Observable <Array<Form>> ;
  public assignedForms$: Observable <Array<Form>> ;
  public form$: Observable <Form>;
  constructor(
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private authService: AuthService,
  ) {}

  getForms() {
    return zip(this.authService.user$).pipe(
      flatMap(data => {
        return this.afs.collection('networks')
          .doc(data[0].activeNetworkProfile.id)
          .collection('companyProfiles')
          .doc(data[0].activeCompanyProfile.id)
          .collection<Forms>('inspectionForms')
          .valueChanges();
      })
    );
  }

}
```

Then in the ListFormsComponent:

```
export class ListFormsComponent implements OnInit {
  public forms: Forms[];
  constructor(
    private formService: FormService, 
    private navigateService: NavigationService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formService.getForms().subscribe(forms => {
      this.forms = forms;
      console.log("Forms inside component");
      console.log(this.forms);
    });
  }

}
```

Also, I won't need to call `getForms` from `navigateForms` now. So I could get rid of that:

```
navigateForms() {
  this.navigateService.navigate('forms');
}
```

Comment: the error isnt there, its in the subscription code inside ListFormsComponent.ts

Comment: Yes I could do it that way but i wanted to have forms$ shared across multiple components. Well I guess I don't really need to since ill most likely just render one component at a time. Ill rewrite the code and see how it works. Ill will update shortly.

Comment: Sounds like a plan :)

Comment: Worked like a charm, I ended up using switchMap as I only needed the latest value.